# In pipeline variable increment

Tags: powershell

I want to

**a)** Display all results for a given service if found

**b)** If no services are found at all, display an appropriate error

The code below will achieve **a)**, how do I achieve **b)** in the tidiest manner. Can I extend the pipe so it pipes to something like **| Set-Variable $serviceCount++** and then check that variable and if it is zero display a message?

```
foreach($service in $services)
{        
    Get-Service | where {$_.Name -eq $service}  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-Name` parameter of the `Get-Service` cmdlet accepts an array of `String`s, so you can replace your loop with simply this:

```
Get-Service -Name $services
```

To check how many services were returned, you can take the result of the `Get-Service` call, convert it to an array (if it is not one already), and store it in a variable:

```
$results = @(Get-Service -Name $services)
```

Then check the length of the array:

```
if ($results.Length -eq 0)
{
    Write-Warning 'No services were found!'
}
```

Note that an error will be thrown for each name passed to the `-Name` parameter that does not correspond to an installed service.  You can suppress these errors using the `-ErrorAction` parameter:

```
Get-Service -Name $services -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```